# Can't understand dq and directly addressing memory

Tags: pointers, assembly, memory, x86-64

I'm reading Low Level Programming by Igor Zhirkov, currently in topic 2.5 about addressing.
He shows a way to directly address memory, the example is as follows:

```
buffer: dq 8841, 99, 00
...
mov rax, [buffer + 8]
```

I know the `dq` creates a qword, but these values don't tell me anything about its purpose. The author says "the address in this instruction was preprocessed, as the base and the offset are constants controlled by the compiler".

Can anyone help me understand this statement?

Comment: He's saying `buffer+8` is a single address, there's no run-time `+8` as part of the addressing.  So it can assemble to a mov with a RIP-relative addressing mode, just like `mov rax, [buffer]` but with a different address.  Either way it's loading 8 bytes into RAX, from static storage.  The C equivalent is `static uint64_t buffer[] = {8841, 99, 0};` and then in some function, `uint64_t foo = buffer[1];` which doesn't have any purpose either.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for the patience to explain!